# Modificar la escala de colores de un mapa de calor

Tags: r

A partir de un dataframe como este:

```
 tbl_ready_selected:

        Genus     B.A  H.G J.I   D.C
       AT1G05830    0   0   0   1.2324233
       AT1G10570    0   0   0   1.2780808
       AT1G30970    0   0   0   0.8711085
       AT1G32230    0   0   0   0.7508349
       AT1G75060    0   0   0   1.0433496
       AT1G77080    0   0   0   1.2596738
       AT2G21070    0   0   0   0.7407752
       AT2G30120    0   0   0   0.7153703
       AT2G31650    0   0   0   0.8639649
       AT2G38880    0   0   0   0.7211602
       AT2G40080    0   1.9466539   2.1552949   1.8718022
       AT3G01090    0   0   0   0.9748342
       AT3G07650    0   1.1429923   1.3678323   0.9265472
       AT3G20740    0   0   0   0.8925632
       AT3G20810    0   2.453158    1.6706815   1.0761394
       AT3G33520    0   0   0   1.0986123
       AT3G44680    0   0   0   0.8407832
       AT3G45880    0   0   0   1.1180304
       AT3G49660    0   0   0   0.7073318
       AT3G54990    0   0   0   0.7832983
       AT3G57230    0   1.1300756   1.4177106   1.8635263
       AT4G10180    0   0   0   0.7887468
       AT4G29830    0   0   0   0.8243894
       AT4G32980    0   0   0   0.817536
       AT4G38960    0   0   0   0.8846854
       AT5G37260    0   2.3534435   1.8281271   0.7239188
       vAT5G42400   0   0   0   0.9785946
       AT5G44200    0   0   0   0.7540179
       AT5G51230    0   0   0.7096765   1.2967892
       AT5G60100    0   0.9545729   1.3752851   2.3665938
       AT5G60120    0   0   0   1.1365032
       AT5G61380    0   0.9221766   1.1519273   1.1148398
       AT5G65050    0   0   0   1.7917595
       AT5G67180    0   0   0   0.9597758
```

he ejecutado el siguiente código para hacer un mapa de calor

```
      tbl_ready_selected <- as.matrix(tbl_ready_selected)
      mode(tbl_ready_selected)<-"numeric"
      is.na(tbl_ready_selected) <- sapply(tbl_ready_selected, is.infinite) 
      tbl_ready_selected[is.na(tbl_ready_selected)] <- 0.02
      tbl_ready_selected[is.nan(tbl_ready_selected)] <- 0.02
      par(cex.main=1, cex.lab=1.2, cex.axis=1.2)


      heatmap.2(tbl_ready_selected, key=TRUE,col = colorRampPalette(c("darkblue","white","darkred"))
      (100), margins=c(6,6),trace="none")
```

obteniendo un resultado como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber como cambiar la gama de colores, que vayan de -4 a 4 siendo el 0 el blanco. Ya que anteriormente hice muchas gráficas que oscilaban entre estos valores siendo el blanco el 0 y me gustaría estandarlizarlo.

Un ejemplo de una gráfica anterior es este:

a partir de un dataframe como este (datos2_4):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13rj4nTJ2Bpd2IpP0uN2gbLKswSVj7tL0/view?usp=sharing

```
         datos2_4 <- as.matrix(datos2_4)
         mode(datos2_4)<-"numeric"

         heatmap.2(datos2_4, key=TRUE,col =   colorRampPalette(c("darkblue","white","darkred"))
      (100), margins=c(6,6),labRow = FALSE,trace="none")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a que apuntas. La escala de colores se construye según los valores de cada variable, en tu primer ejemplo, los valores oscilan entre 0 y 2.5, ¿Por que dices que quieres la escala de -4 a 4? Acaso, quieres trabajar con la paleta que va de -4 a 4, pero solo con la porción de 0 a 2.5? Si es esto se necesita conocer los valores que construyen la segunda gráfica.

Comment: Exactamente es eso, para que todas las gráficas tengan la mis.a leyenda de colores. El código de la segunda gráfica es el mismo que el de la primera. Ahora mismo añado los valores de la segunda gráfica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, he conseguido cambiarlo añadiendo detrás de mi código esto:

```
symm=F,symkey=F,symbreaks=T, scale="none"
```

De esta manera hago que el rango de color sea asimétrico simplemente cambiando el argumento `symkey` a `FALSE`